# Which Operating Systems are officially supported?

Tags: validator

Windows and macOS are being mentioned a few times on docs.substrate.io, but the Substrate CI does not run tests on there.
Now my question; what are the officially supported OS?
With "officially supported" I mean that its a safe choice for validators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only "safe" choice is Linux. As you already mentioned, we only test on Linux, and most validators also run on Linux. For macOS, we only ensure that it compiles because a lot of developers are running on macOS. We also have some performance optimization around Wasm execution that is only for Linux/macOS. Windows is not really supported. We probably compile on Windows, but not that much more support is provided. The Linux subsystem should be used on Windows to get the best compatibility.

Comment: Just to clarify the situation on macOS. The support is limited. For example, we make sure that it compiles, but we don't run tests for it. It's only meant for developers, and it's discouraged to run production code on macOS. This may change in the future.